# Dot git config file not reflecting when switch user on ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Tags: bash, git, zsh, user-profile, ubuntu-22.04

Today I have installed Ubuntu22.04LTS. In that, i had a user bob and his git config is like

```
user.name=Bob B
user.email=bob@example.com
alias.unadd=reset HEAD
```

I Had another user named quealy . when I switched to the user quealy. using sudo -s -u quealy the bob gitconfig setting not reflecting.

Previously, I encountered a similar issue on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. However, I was able to resolve it by creating and adding the following configuration.

```
sudo visudo -f /etc/sudoers.d/keep-home with Defaults    env_keep += "HOME"
```

I followed the same but not working in Ubuntu22.04LTS.

Comment: So the question is how to get a shell impersonating another user while maintaining the home dir of the current user. Sound like a question for https://askubuntu.com/ or https://superuser.com/